# react: Failing to load an image from a local api path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a very basic one, but for some reason only the first  tag loads the image, while the other two do not.
I've included the 'require' function as I've seen in other threads, but still to no success.
My use-case is loading these paths from an api that's run locally, and has URI references to images also stored locally. These paths are outside of the project directory of my react app.
i.e:

- React app makes request to local REST api, which responds with some JSON
- React app uses a map function to loop through local paths inside the JSON, e.g: /some/local/absolute/path/image.jpg
- React app wraps the paths within an `<img src={path-var}>`

Any idea how to make this work?

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../my-icon.jpg"


class App extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={logo}/> # WORKS
                <img src={"/Users/my-user/repos/app/python-backend/images/my-icon.jpg"}/> # DOESN'T WORK
                <img src={require("/Users/my-user/repos/app/python-backend/images/my-icon.jpg")}/> # DOESN'T WORK
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you run this in your browser and examine the resulting markup with your browser's debugging tools, what is the resulting `src` value used in the "working" version?  How does it differ from the resulting `src` values used in the "non-working" versions?  I suspect that's your answer...

Comment: So the path of the "working" version is: /static/media/my-icon.46cf6385ce51ce58abfc.jpg 
So it has its own way of finding the path when it's imported + show a relative path. So maybe React doesn't like being given full paths to other parts of the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two separate things here:

1. How the React code imports a file and uses it in JSX markup, ultimately creating the resulting HTML markup.
2. How the browser uses that resulting HTML markup.

When you do this:

```
import logo from "../my-icon.jpg"

// and later...
<img src={logo}/>
```

The resulting `src` value in the HTML will have been translated into something else entirely.  The build process for the application knows that `my-icon.jpg` needs to be included in the bundled build output, and the `src` value will be a relative URL to that resulting resource.

But when you do this:

```
<img src={"/Users/my-user/repos/app/python-backend/images/my-icon.jpg"}/>
```

The build process doesn't have anything to change.  You've provided it with a literal string, which will be the exact output in the resulting HTML.

However, according to the problem you've observed, the literal string you're providing here is *not* the relative URL of the file.  The `/Users` part of this suggests that this is likely a *file system path* on your `C:\` drive.  The web server and the file system are two entirely different things.

If you're providing a string value as the `src`, it will need to be a correct URL to the image file in the build output of the application.

How are you including that file in your application?  Does this `images` folder which contains the file get included in your resulting website?  If so then `/images/my-icon.jpg` may work.  But ultimately, if you're getting these string values from data, then you're going to have to determine how the resulting web application can reference the files indicated by that data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes exactly right, the images are on my local machine's hard drive.
But is it not possible at all to access these hard-drive images? Because the api is giving the app a path which leads to an image, and the app just needs to display that image. Is there a way to translate this path information from the api into a form which allows react to grab the image?

Comment: @solarflare: Keep in mind again the difference between the web site/server and the file system.  Just because a file is *on your hard drive* doesn't mean it's (A) accessible via a local web server or (B) accessible to any user who accesses a published/deployed version of this web application.  Forgetting the `<img>` element for a moment, if you were to enter a URL for this file manually as part of the website URL structure (*not* a `file://` URL), what would that URL be?  That is, where are you sharing these files on the website?  That's the URL you'd use in the `src` value.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm probably lacking some fundamental understanding then!
I assumed these local hard drive files could be accessed like any other data host if run locally...
If I were to create a network drive to host these images, and the api's json paths pointed to these image locations, would that allow react to access these images while I'm within the network?

Comment: You're still thinking about the URLs in terms of a file system.  The fact that they're on the hard drive instead of on a network drive doesn't make a difference.  They need to be within the *web server's path* in order to be accessed by that website.  For example, if the root path of a web server is at `C:\some\path` then the URL `/` points to that folder.  If you add a folder called `images` in that folder then it would be accessible under `/images`.  And so on.  If you have a bunch of image files to share in your website then they need to be part of the website.

Comment: Ok thank you for this, it clears things up!
But what if I want to load my images from an external source, rather than having to upload them with my website?

Comment: @solarflare: Are the *paths* to the images coming from an external source (but the images themselves are part of your website), or are the *images themselves* coming from an external source?  If the latter then the question becomes, how is that external source making the images available for users to view them?

Comment: ok thank you very much, this has been very helpful! I've definitely been thinking about this idea quite wrong... 
I will be hosting the api (and also the images) externally in a format accessible over the Internet in future